# Using same view for editing and viewing symfony

Tags: php, rest, symfony

I'd like to use the same view for both editing and viewing. Unfortunatly, I cannot edit my view. In symfony3, I think there is no way to index a form. I tried every thing I could but I don't know how I can use the same form. In my project, I use also JEE (linked directly to data base) to communicate with symfony using UniRest API. Here are my view and edit controllers:

```
  /**
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
  public function viewAction($id) {
  $phone = new Phone();
  $form = $this->createForm(PhoneType::class, $phone);
  $headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json');
  $response = Unirest\Request::get(link/phones/'.$id,$headers);
  //$this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $response->getStatusCode());
  return $this->render('AppBundle:Phone:PhoneView.html.twig', array (
      'form' => $form->createView(),
      'phone' => $response->body,
             ) );
     }


  /**
* @Method({"PUT"})
*/
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {

  $phone = new Phone();
  $form = $this->createForm(PhoneType::class, $phone);
  dump($request->getMethod());
    if ($request->isMethod('PUT')) {
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
    $data = json_encode($phone);
    $response = Unirest\Request::put('link/phones/'.$id,$headers,$data);
    //$this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $response->getStatusCode());
    dump($response->code);
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('phones_list'));
  }
  $headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json');
  $response = Unirest\Request::get('link/phones/'.$id,$headers);
  //$this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $response->getStatusCode());
  dump($response->code);
  dump($response->body);
   return $this->render('AppBundle:Phone:PhoneUpdate.html.twig',    array(
     'form'=> $form->createView(),
     'phone'=> $response->body,
   ));
```

And here is my file **PhoneView.html.twig**

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}Accedant - {{ parent() }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<form novalidate="novalidate" method = "get">
 <p>
 <label> color </label> :<input type="text" value= {{ phone.color }} />          
 <label> price </label> :<input type="text" value= {{ phone.price }} /> 
    <div class="form-group col-md-offset-5">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </div>
  </p>
 </form>

{# Updating Phone #}
<p class="left-center">
    <a href="{{ path('phones_update', {'id': phone.id}) }}" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger">
        Modify phone
     </a>
  </p>
{% endblock %}
```

And here is my **PhoneUpdate.html.twig**

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block title %} Phone - {{ parent() }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">

{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'PUT'}) }}
<input type="hidden" name'_METHOD' value="PUT">
{{ form_widget(form) }}
  <input type="submit" value="Sauvegarder" class="btn btn-default" />
{{ form_end(form) }}


</div>

{% endblock %}
```

and here is my file **routing.yml**

```
phones_view:
path:     /phones/{id}
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Phone:view }
methods:  [GET]
requirements:
    id:  \d+


phones_update:
 path:     /phones/{id}
 methods:  [PUT]
 defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Phone:update }

 requirements:
     id:  \d+
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean with "index the form"? Do you mean that you want to render the same form multiple times but that you need additional information in the action? There are surely a few options to do that. One is to add a variable to the route that calls the action that processes the form (ig /phone/{id}/create) and then change the action attribute for each form that you render with the correct id. Another option would be to use an hidden field inside your form.

Comment: I mean that I want to give an index to the form, so that I can use the same form for viewing and editing. Actually, I can create a form and I can list my phones and I can also view them, but the problem is that I cannot edit them, can you give me details about the other option please (use an hidden field inside your form) ?

Comment: To edit your form you need to pre populate the form with existing data and then move on to solving the issue of adding empty fields to your form so the user can add stuff as well. So instead of making new phone object, use an existing relevant one.

Comment: That's exactly the problem, I don't know how to make reference to them in my form, how can I use a form who is already created, that's why I am saying that I need to index them in order to make a reference for them in my **PhoneUpdate.Twig.html** could you write for me the file PhoneUpdateTwig.html (my problem is here) I think the controller is good.

Comment: in `updateAction()` you are passing new `Phone` object to form with your code `$phone = new Phone();
  $form = $this->createForm(PhoneType::class, $phone);`
So instead passing new `Phone()` object find the one you need by `$id` `$phone = $phoneRepository->find($id); $form = $this->createForm(PhoneType::class, $phone);`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a variable called $phoneRepository in my code. I guess $ phoneRepository = this->getDoctrine() .., but the problem is that I am not using Doctrine, I am using UniRest API to communicate with JEE who is linked directly with database. Could I do this without using Doctrine. The other operations works well, I can create, list, delete phones but I cannot edit them.

Comment: I would like to do that without using Doctrine. My database is linked to JEE so I would like to use APIUnirest. My problem is that in my url link/phones/id even if I click ** Modify phone** the code executed is the view code (Twig and controller). I never execute my edit code even if in my **routing.yml** file I specified the method (put , get).

Comment: That was a configuration problem, but I should modify my code in order to make this work

Answer (score 0):

First of all, my **put** and **delete** method was not configurated. Moreover, my problem was that I thought   that the **put** method in my routing file **routing.yml** has no relation with my web services. So I change my path in order to edit my form **/update/{id}**, and after that I got a 404 error that was because of my implementation in J2EE side.